# How to set flags as -1 for n-1 rows before a cell in python(to drop)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, flags

How do I set the n-1 values before a flag value to -1 as I need to drop the n-1 values before the flag value
for example, if the flag value is 4, I need to set the previous 3 rows to -1.

Example Table

| UID | exclusion_flag |
| --- | --- |
| 1BOP2UC-1 | 0 |
| 1BOP2UC-2 | 0 |
| 1BOP2UC-3 | 0 |
| 1BOP2UC-4 | 4 |
| 1BOP2UC-5 | 0 |
| 1BOP2UC-6 | 0 |
| 1BOP2UC-7 | 0 |
| 1BOP2UC-8 | 2 |
| 1BOP2UC-9 | 0 |
| 1BOP2UD-1 | 0 |
| 1BOP2UD-2 | 0 |
| 1BOP2UD-3 | 0 |
| 1BOP2UD-4 | 0 |
| 1BOP2UD-5 | 4 |

Required Solution

| UID | exclusion_flag |
| --- | --- |
| 1BOP2UC-1 | -1 |
| 1BOP2UC-2 | -1 |
| 1BOP2UC-3 | -1 |
| 1BOP2UC-4 | 4 |
| 1BOP2UC-5 | 0 |
| 1BOP2UC-6 | 0 |
| 1BOP2UC-7 | -1 |
| 1BOP2UC-8 | 2 |
| 1BOP2UC-9 | 0 |
| 1BOP2UD-1 | 0 |
| 1BOP2UD-2 | -1 |
| 1BOP2UD-3 | -1 |
| 1BOP2UD-4 | -1 |
| 1BOP2UD-5 | 4 |

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing any of your data nor any of the code that you have written that produces your problem. Please review Jon Skeet's excellent blog post [WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) for guidance in updating your question.  For a more detailed tutorial on asking a good question see Eric S. Raymond's site [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether question is still actual, but this is my solution:

1. I initialize `mem` variable wich represents counter.
2. I iterate thru list backwards using `reversed` function.
3. If actual value is greater than zero, I want to overwrite `mem` with actual value otherwise, `mem -1`. I don't want counter to be negative, therefore `max(0, mem-1)`.
4. If `mem` is greater then zero, it means we are still counting rows, mark row to -1.
5. If `mem` equals to `x` this is row, where our counter sequence started, and we want to keep `x` besides `out`.
6. I return the `out_arr` again in correct order.

```py
from typing import List
import pandas as pd

dummy_col = [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2]
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(col1=dummy_col))


def fun(arr: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    mem = 0
    out_arr = []
    for x in reversed(arr):
        mem = x if x > 0 else max(0, mem - 1)
        out = -1 if mem > 0 else 0
        out = x if mem == x else out
        out_arr += [out]
    return list(reversed(out_arr))


df['final_col'] = fun(arr=df['col1'].to_list())
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
   col1  final_col
0     0          0
1     0         -1
2     0         -1
3     0         -1
4     4          4
5     0          0
6     0          0
7     0         -1
8     2          2
```